# SwiftUI: Animate Cells within a Form

Tags: swift, forms, animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate my `Form` or rather the cells within it. My problem is that the following code give me a nice insertion animation but for the removal the cell is suddenly removed after am ugly looking delay.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggledValue = false
    @State var pickedValue = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Toggle(isOn: $toggledValue) {
                        Text("Toggled Value")
                    }

                    if toggledValue {
                        Picker(selection: $pickedValue, label: Text("Picked Value")) {
                            ForEach((0...5).identified(by: \.self)) {
                                Text("Pick Value \($0)").tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Some Text")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Navigation Bar Title")
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far is to to wrap the `Toggle` in a `withAnimation` closure but this does not change anything. What makes me wondering is that the same code using `List` instead of `Form` gives me the expected Animation. Is that a bug or am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work (tested in iOS 16 in [a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75046276/1971013)):

- Add `@State private var isShowingPicker = false`
- Replace `if toggledValue` by `if isShowingPicker`
- Under `.navigationBarTitle(...)` add:

```
   onChange(of: toggledValue)
   { newValue in
       withAnimation { isShowingPicker = newValue }
   }
```