# How to animate Form cell to [dis]appear?

Tags: ios, swift, forms, animation, swiftui

I have the following:

```
struct HelloView
{
    @State private var name: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationStack
        {
            Form
            {
                Section
                {
                    TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)

                    if !name.isEmpty
                    {
                        Button("Save name")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Hello")
    }
}
```

When starting to enter the name, the button cell appears suddenly.  How can this be animated?

[This is a very similar question from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57307392/1971013) that was never answered.

I'm on iOS 16.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

This will probably work (tested in iOS 16 in a similar situation):

- Add `@State private var isShowingButton = false`
- Replace `if !name.isEmpty` by `if isShowingButton`
- Under `.navigationTitle(...)` add:

```
   onChange(of: name)
   { newValue in
       withAnimation { isShowingButton = newValue }
   }
```

But I'm wondering if there's no simpler solution.